# Can not push any commits to Heroku for Jekyll site (App crashed H10 error)

Tags: git, heroku, github, jekyll

I have a Jekyll site deployed to Heroku. I made some changes to one of the posts, but when I tried to push it to Heroku I got an application error H10 App crashed. (Although the site is working locally and I haven't edited anything but the text.)

I deleted the last commit by running:

```
$ git reset HEAD^ --hard
$ git push -f
```

Then I tried to make a forced update to Heroku by running `git push heroku master -f`, but I got an application error again.

So I rolled back the site to the last working version through Heroku dashboard. Now it's on the same commit as Github. But when I try to commit any new changes to Heroku I get this error:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/iloveip.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

If I first run `git pull heroku master` and then `git push heroku master` I still get an application error.

Here are some Heroku logs, when I try to make forced updates:

```
MacBook-Pro-Svetlana:iloveip svetlana$ heroku logs
2016-01-15T16:13:35.030515+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/main.css" host=iloveip.herokuapp.com request_id=1df0cadc-2f61-4cc7-a59e-e8bd01ec3088 fwd="176.77.114.115" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=304 bytes=179
2016-01-15T16:13:28.213123+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-01-15T16:13:20.055459+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-01-15T16:19:02.226238+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/kb/insurance-deductions/" host=iloveip.herokuapp.com request_id=eda699c2-b5e6-4ccc-a74c-7a44004aabb8 fwd="176.77.114.115" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=22910
2016-01-15T16:19:02.506201+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/jquery.reGrid.min.js" host=iloveip.herokuapp.com request_id=6c5ede4c-2088-45d5-a0b5-6b65315445a0 fwd="176.77.114.115" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=304 bytes=179
2016-01-15T16:19:02.624172+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/search.js" host=iloveip.herokuapp.com request_id=645f6bb6-9a5b-4cef-b0e8-6b6de25eb5e1 fwd="176.77.114.115" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=20ms status=304 bytes=179
2016-01-15T16:19:02.636822+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/main.js" host=iloveip.herokuapp.com request_id=f59c2aa4-b4bc-443e-b677-ef2821a4fd6d fwd="176.77.114.115" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=12ms status=304 bytes=179
2016-01-15T16:19:02.516212+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/icon-font/styles.css" host=iloveip.herokuapp.com request_id=18022950-ca84-4d21-bc2d-5b28078e5cbc fwd="176.77.114.115" dyno=web.1 connect=10ms service=20ms status=304 bytes=179
2016-01-15T16:19:02.504723+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/octicons/octicons.css" host=iloveip.herokuapp.com request_id=f131dc4d-5493-4f08-a90e-5b9cf8dbba02 fwd="176.77.114.115" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=14ms status=304 bytes=179
2016-01-15T16:19:02.507519+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/main.css" host=iloveip.herokuapp.com request_id=ae65e9fd-7520-4703-bd1d-f3c25840f3db fwd="176.77.114.115" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=14ms status=304 bytes=179
2016-01-15T16:26:01.681584+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-01-15T16:26:01.681589+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-01-15T16:26:01.543736+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 8db9082 by jupiteror1@yahoo.com
2016-01-15T16:26:01.543736+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v178 created by jupiteror1@yahoo.com
2016-01-15T16:26:01.677805+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2016-01-15T16:26:04.936001+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 43824`
2016-01-15T16:26:05.348235+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-01-15T16:26:06.484965+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-15 16:26:06] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2016-01-15T16:26:06.484970+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:174:in `select'
2016-01-15T16:26:06.484972+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:174:in `block in start'
2016-01-15T16:26:06.484973+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2016-01-15T16:26:06.484973+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
2016-01-15T16:26:06.484974+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:34:in `run'
2016-01-15T16:26:06.484975+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
2016-01-15T16:26:06.484976+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:147:in `start'
2016-01-15T16:26:06.484976+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
2016-01-15T16:26:06.484977+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
2016-01-15T16:26:06.484978+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
2016-01-15T16:26:06.485082+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-15 16:26:06] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2016-01-15T16:26:06.485138+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-15 16:26:06] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2016-01-15T16:26:06.528650+00:00 app[web.1]: Generating site: /app -> /app/_site
2016-01-15T16:26:07.299861+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212287+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0.pre.rc1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:97:in `setup'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212250+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/_plugins/page_view.rb:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- google/api_client (LoadError)
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212281+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0.pre.rc1/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:75:in `require'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212292+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212300+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212282+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0.pre.rc1/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in require_plugin_files'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212290+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `new'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212293+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212279+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/_plugins/page_view.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212289+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/rack-jekyll-d5a58846ac23/lib/rack/jekyll.rb:39:in `initialize'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212293+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212284+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0.pre.rc1/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:74:in `block in require_plugin_files'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212297+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212283+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0.pre.rc1/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:74:in `each'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212288+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/rack-jekyll-d5a58846ac23/lib/rack/jekyll.rb:39:in `new'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212295+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212284+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0.pre.rc1/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:73:in `each'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212301+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212285+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0.pre.rc1/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:73:in `require_plugin_files'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212294+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212298+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212328+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212286+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0.pre.rc1/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:18:in `conscientious_require'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212331+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212288+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0.pre.rc1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:49:in `initialize'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212294+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212333+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.224161+00:00 app[web.1]: Configuration file: /app/_config.yml
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212303+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212329+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:147:in `start'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.212332+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
2016-01-15T16:26:08.926498+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-01-15T16:26:08.926498+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-01-15T16:26:08.927121+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-01-15T16:26:11.395852+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 39364`
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977665+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/_plugins/page_view.rb:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- google/api_client (LoadError)
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977694+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/_plugins/page_view.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977696+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0.pre.rc1/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:75:in `require'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977697+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0.pre.rc1/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in require_plugin_files'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977698+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0.pre.rc1/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:74:in `each'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977698+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0.pre.rc1/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:74:in `block in require_plugin_files'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977699+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0.pre.rc1/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:73:in `each'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977703+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0.pre.rc1/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:73:in `require_plugin_files'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977704+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0.pre.rc1/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:18:in `conscientious_require'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977705+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0.pre.rc1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:97:in `setup'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977705+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0.pre.rc1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:49:in `initialize'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977706+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/rack-jekyll-d5a58846ac23/lib/rack/jekyll.rb:39:in `new'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977707+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/rack-jekyll-d5a58846ac23/lib/rack/jekyll.rb:39:in `initialize'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977708+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `new'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977709+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977709+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977710+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977711+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977711+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977712+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977713+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977714+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977714+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977715+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977716+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977717+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:147:in `start'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977718+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977716+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.986304+00:00 app[web.1]: Configuration file: /app/_config.yml
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977718+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977719+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
2016-01-15T16:26:14.635692+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-01-15T16:26:14.617586+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-01-15T16:26:16.318196+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/kb/insurance-deductions/" host=iloveip.herokuapp.com request_id=cfcb8881-fd0e-4969-a30b-7c05a265c0da fwd="176.77.114.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by `google-api-client` gem. See this line:

```
2016-01-15T16:26:13.977665+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/_plugins/page_view.rb:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- google/api_client (LoadError)
```

I put the following in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'google-api-client', '0.8.6', require: 'google/api_client'
```

Updated bundle and it's working now.